# TitledPane. Ручной контроль

Tags: javafx

Имеется TitledPane. Как вручную контролировать её выпадение и скрытие?

Comment: expandedProperty?

Comment: TitiledPane.setExpanded(true\false);

Answer (score 0):

```
tp //указатель на TitledPane 
tp.setExpanded(true);
```

Вот так можно сворачивать и разворачивать в коде TitledPane.